# How to get a next alphabet in alphabetical sequence in apex class?

Tags: apex

How can I get the next alphabetical character in alphabetical sequence?
ex. I have  'A' letter, I want 'B' by using 'A'.

Comment: Using a Map : `Map<String, String> m = new Map<String, String>{'A' =>'B', 'B'=> 'C', ...};`

Comment: What do you want to happen for 'Z' and 'z'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use String.indexOfChar to find the next value in a simple string. Here's an example:

```
public static String getNextChar(String oldChar) {
    String key = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza';
    Integer index = key.indexOfChar(oldChar.charAt(0));
    return index == -1? null: key.substring(index+1, index+2);
}
```

This includes automatic wraparound from Z -> A and z -> a.

Answer (score 7):

The methods you'll want to use are listed in the `Apex Developer Guide` under  **[String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)**, specifically `charAt` and `fromCharArray`.

```
Integer charCode = 'A'.charAt(0);
List<Integer> chars = new List<Integer>{charCode+1};
String nextChar = String.fromCharArray(chars);
System.assertEquals('B', nextChar);
```

Comment: your ans is also correct, but in case of 'Z' letter '[' comes  as a next char.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the ASCII values (see http://www.asciitable.com/).  In this example, A is 65 and B is 66.  A simple numeric increment will get you to the next value.  To convert the numeric value back to a character, you can use

```
String myChar = String.fromCharArray( new List<integer> { 65 } );
```

where the number is the ASCII value of the letter you need.

Comment: and this should cover the lower case variants (a=97, b=98 etc)

Comment: Ok, the answer by @frontendloader is better than mine...use that one :-)